# How to mount dirs from disk

Tags: linux, debian, proxmox

I'm using Proxmox 6 and I have an HDD with two folders in it: `backups` and `syncthing-data`.

I want to use the `backups` folder as a directory for proxmox vms/containers backups and the `syncthing-data` as mounted disk in a VM.

How I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Proxmox Web administration interface, go to Datacenter --> Storage
Add a new storage type. Choose directory:

[image]

Choose an ID (i.e. MyImages, MyBackup)

Choose the folder you need (in your case backups and syncthing-data)

For Images, select content to be Disk Image

For Backup, select content to be VZDump backup file